# endpoints group by http method in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have multiple controller each having GET, POST, PUT, DELETE apis. By default swagger grouping apis at controller level. Is there any way to group these apis by http method type in swagger doc.? i.e GET apis together , POST apis together etc.

Comment: What library/framework do you use (e.g. Swashbuckle, Springfox, Swagger-PHP, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "tags" section at the level of each api path , that you are defining . This is how you tag an API path in swagger as below .

```
paths:
  /pet:
    post:
      tags:   // This is where you provide your method type to group all your APIs for a given http method . Same you can do to tag "GET" methods .
      - "POST"
      summary: "Add a new pet to the store"
      description: ""
      operationId: "addPet"
```

For all get APIs , you can provide tag as "GET", "POST" for post apis and so on . I set up an example for you , which might help you visualise .

[image]